# Powershell Scripts inconsistent behavior

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have two powershell scripts that revolve around abandoned accounts.  These scripts should exclude six specific OUs in our environment.  The first reports all accounts that will require action.  The second takes action and disables the accounts based on the same criteria.

For reasons I can't figure out, the disable script is leaving behind users across multiple OUs that it is not taking action on. Any help at all will be appreciated.

Here's the reporting version:

```
  import-module activedirectory

$datestring = Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy
$oldDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-45)
$OUDN1 = "OU=Resource accounts,OU=Domain Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN2 = "OU=Service Accounts,OU=Domain Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN3 = "OU=DO NOT DELETE,OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN4 = "CN=Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN5 = "OU=User Templates,OU=Domain Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN6 = "CN=Microsoft Exchange System Objects,DC=placeholder,DC=org"

Get-ADUser -filter {(Enabled -eq $True) -AND ((LastLogonDate -lt $olddate) -OR ((LastLogonDate -notlike "*") -AND (WhenCreated -lt $olddate)))} -Properties DisplayName,Name,LastLogonDate,Modified,info,description,sAMAccountName,WhenCreated | Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN1") -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN2") -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN3")-and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN4") -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN5") -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN6")} | Select sAMAccountName,Name,description,LastLogonDate,WhenCreated,Modified,DistinguishedName | Export-CSV c:\Reports\nolog45_$datestring.csv
```

And here's the action version:

```
import-module activedirectory

$disUsers = @()
$oldDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-45)
$OUDN1 = "OU=Resource accounts,OU=Domain Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN2 = "OU=Service Accounts,OU=Domain Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN3 = "OU=DO NOT DELETE,OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN4 = "CN=Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN5 = "OU=User Templates,OU=Domain Users,DC=placeholder,DC=org"
$OUDN6 = "CN=Microsoft Exchange System Objects,DC=placeholder,DC=org"

$disUsers = Get-ADUser -filter {(Enabled -eq $True) -AND (LastLogonDate -lt $olddate)} -Properties sAMAccountName,Name,SID,Enabled,LastLogonDate,Modified,info,description,DistinguishedName | Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN1") -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN2") -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN3")-and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN4") -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN5")  -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$OUDN6")} 

foreach ($name in $disUsers) {
        $DistName = $name.DistinguishedName
        Disable-ADAccount -Identity $DistName -ErrorAction Continue
        }
```

Today's run for example left 30 accounts that the report script found still enabled.  It wasn't permissions, because I could disable the same accounts manually with no problems.  No red text was generated, no error output - just seemingly ignored the accounts.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria in both scripts is not the same.

Your reporting script has this, which your action script does not:

```
 -OR ((LastLogonDate -notlike "*") -AND (WhenCreated -lt $olddate))
```

Comment: Ahhh, I knew I had missed something simple.  That criteria was added at the last minute and I failed to move it to the action script.  Thank you very much for the assist!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help! :)